# Is layover of 1hr enough at Nassau Airport to catch flight to Eleuthera?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, airport-security, bahamas, nas

We will be arriving from USA to Nassau and our connecting flight leaves exactly 1hr after we arrive so is that enough time to catch it when going to ELH (N. Eleuthera)?

Is there a customs line we have to go thru?

We can take a different flight that is a 1-stop and get there in enough time but that means leaving at 5am in the morning plus a 1-stop also may have it's own set of issues so should we chance it?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What time do you arrive?

Comment: tx K. we arrive on a saturday at 2:45p and bahama air leaves at 3:45p. that is the last flight of the day unfortunately + pineapple air also leaves at 3:45p on the same day and that is their last flight so if we miss it, we are going to be out of luck.

Comment: I will give a more detailed answer tomorrow based on what flights will be arriving around the same time.  But you should consider arriving on an earlier flight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One hour is not impossible, but it's cutting it mighty close -- I probably would not take the risk.  Bahamasair's [official recommendation](http://bahamasair.com/policies/check-in-requirements-and-baggage-acceptance-cutoff-times/?phpMyAdmin=10fc503501ebt7eb9b0b4) is checking in two hours before departure, with a cut-off at 30 min, although I'm not sure how strictly this is enforced (it's a pint-sized airport after all).  They are notoriously flaky though, and the veiled threat about getting bumped off even a confirmed flight if you don't show up at least an hour beforehand should be taken seriously.

Nevertheless, if you figure on 10 min to get to immigration, 0 to 30 min waiting in line (use the Interisland Transit line on the right, it'll be slightly faster), then 10 min to walk over to the domestic terminal, the odds are two in three that you'll miss the 30 min cutoff.  And that's assuming you have no checked bags and that your flight lands precisely on time.

Comment: tx jp, since it's a connector via Delta and we set it up thru them. will they transfer our checked bags over to bahama air or will we need to get them ourselves after immigration, then head over to bahama air? is that the steps we'd be taking...

Comment: So you're saying Delta sold you this route as single ticket?  Then I'd be a bit more comfortable, since then they're responsible.  But yes, you have to pass through immigration/customs in Nassau and recheck your bags.

Comment: Also, have you looked into Silver Airways?  They fly direct to Eleuthera from a few places in the US.

Comment: They don't service my city but I like that they are aggressive with their routes. We purchased them thru an online service like expedia or priceline, I can daable ck w/wife but we did not purchase separately ... the trip was packaged together. I won't be able to select the correct answer until we get back but thanks so far for all the help.

Comment: @Rico: Note that it really makes a difference whether you purchased the whole itinerary directly from a single airline, or whether you bought it through a third-party site like Expedia.  In the former case, the airline will usually take care of you if you miss the connection: rebook you on a new flight, reroute your baggage, etc.  In the latter case, the airline has no responsibility and in principle could say "Sorry, you missed our flight, buy a new ticket".  So it would certainly help if you can be clear about this.

Comment: 1 hour was definitely not enough time but we did get help from the "interisland transit line" on the left hand side which had 0 people in it so getting thru customs was a breeze. we also had to grab our bag from the wrongly marked baggage claim so check them all when you land, that cost us about 10 minutes. after running over to the other terminal we had to cut in line *sorry ppl* but yeah, lots of hecklers but we barely made it on. btw - bahamasair changed our flight time 3x as we initially had 1.5 hrs, two days before it was moved down to 45 min #fail #bahamasair

Answer (score 4):

First off the 1 hour you have left yourself is likely not to be enough and here is why.

Most people who travel on Saturday to the Bahamas are traveling to start their vacation in one of the resorts on the islands and flights are likely to be full on that day.  Keeping that in mind you should realize that most people by the time they arrive are already in the Vacation mode and are operating in "brain off" state.  When you arrive to Bahamas from outside you will have to go through immigration and unless you hold Bahamian citizenship or residency you go in the line with everyone.  And given the number of [flights arriving](http://www.nassaulpia.com/Public/arrivals.aspx) around the time you will be arriving you will be in line with about 400 people.

One of the things I was watching when I stood in that line was that people in their vacation mode don't listen to the flight crews telling them to fill out arrival cards for every member of the family, which they don't do nor do they fill out all required parts.  So what starts to happen is that people will be filling out those cards as they stand in front of the immigration officer delaying the line.  So for us we have arrived at 11:40 but left the airport close to 2pm.

Once you get through that line you will have to collect you luggage, which hopefully makes it to the belt and then through the customs which will make it more or less a formality but still takes time and then re-check to the domestic flight to North Eleuthera.

So all in all I'd leave myself more time then 1 hour to make the flight.